# Show that $|\text{Hom}_k(K,\widetilde{K})(\phi)|\le [K:L]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K/k$ be a finite field extension, $L$ an intermediate field and $\widetilde{K}$ such that $\widetilde{K}/k$ is normal.

Let $\phi \in \text{Hom}_k(L,\widetilde{K}) := \{\psi:L\rightarrow \widetilde{K} \mid \psi\mid_{k}=\text{id}_{L}) \}$ and $\text{Hom}_k(K,\widetilde{K})(\phi) := \{\psi:K\rightarrow \widetilde{K} \mid \psi\mid_{L}=\phi) \}$.

Show that $|\text{Hom}_k(K,\widetilde{K})(\phi)|\le [K:L]$.

---

I already know that when $K = L(a)$ for some element $a \in K$, then $|\text{Hom}_k(K,\widetilde{K})(\phi)|\le [K:L]$.

**Proof:**

Let $g$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $L$ and f the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $k$.
Since $f(a) = 0 \implies g \mid f$ in $L[X] \implies f = gh$ for some polynomial $h$.
We then have $f = \phi(f)=\phi(g)\phi(h)$ with $\phi$ inducing a ring homomorphism $L[X] \rightarrow \widetilde{K}[X]$.

Since $\widetilde{K}/k$ is normal and $a\in K \subset \widetilde{K}$, $f$ splits in $\widetilde{K}$, which implies that $\phi(g)$ splits in $\widetilde{K}$.

Now, $|\text{Hom}_k(K=L(a),\widetilde{K})(\phi)| = |\{b\in \widetilde{K} \mid (\phi(g))(b)=0\}|\le \text{deg}\; \phi(g) = \text{deg}\;g = [L(a):L] = [K:L]$.

---

This was used in the proof of this statement:

$|\text{Hom}_k(K,\widetilde{K})|\le [K:k]$

**Proof:**

$[K:k]\lt \infty \implies K = k(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_r)$

Induction on $r$:

Let $L=k(a_1,\ldots,a_{r-1})$ and $K=L(a_r)$.

By induction we have $m := |\text{Hom}_k(L,\widetilde{K})|\le [L:k]$. Let $\text{Hom}_k(L,\widetilde{K}) = \{\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_m\}$, then we have $\text{Hom}_k(K,\widetilde{K}) = \bigcup_{1\le i\le m} \text{Hom}_k(K,\widetilde{K})(\phi_i)$, where the union is disjoint.

Then, $|\text{Hom}_k(K,\widetilde{K})| = \sum_{i=1}^m |\text{Hom}_k(K,\widetilde{K})(\phi_i)|\le[K:L]m \le [K:L][L:k] = [K:k]$.

---

**Now, the problem is to show that $|\text{Hom}_k(K,\widetilde{K})(\phi)|\le [K:L]$ holds true for arbitrary intermediate fields $L$. I'm pretty sure that I can use the proofs above to show this, but I just don't see it.**

**Do you?**

Comment: In the proof you used an arbitary field $L$, I am somewhat confused. Do you mean arbitary fields $K$ in the final question ?

Comment: Isn't the theorem of the primitive element saying that always $K=L(a)$ ?

Comment: @Peter: K/k is an arbitrary field extension and L is some intermediate field in it. That's what I meant to say.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: That was my first idea, but this is only true if K/k is separable.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: That's an interesting thought.

Comment: You have a typo in the definition of the $k$-morphisms: they should restrict to the identity of $k$, not of $L$.

Comment: You can try to write things out in words. You have a finite field extension $K/k$; an intermediate extension $L/k$ and $\widetilde K/k$ is normal, $\widetilde K\supseteq K$. Given a $k$-morphism $\phi:L\to \widetilde K$, you want to show that $\phi$ can be extended to a $k$-morphism $K\to\widetilde K$ in at most $[K:L]$ ways.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Yes, one can put it that way. Btw, that's no typo, it's just an awkward definition, which I didn't come up with :)